# .net core pinvoke marshalling memory management in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, .net-core, pinvoke, marshalling

According to the .net framework documentation it uses CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree for parameters marshalling.

The question is how does it work in linux ?
For instance, if I want to allocate memory for an out parameter in my native library, can I just use malloc ?

Comment: This discussion seems to indicate you can forward all `CoTaskMemAlloc` calls to `malloc`: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/19082#issuecomment-407105560 (can't find no official/reference doc, but it comes from Microsoft guys ...)